# Difference between checking for a file's existence with NSData or NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to check if a file exists. If I use this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];

if (data == NULL){
   ...
}
```

I always get `NULL`.

Than I found `NSFileManager`:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
```

works as I expect it to. What causes the difference between these two procedures?

Comment: Note that dataWithContentsOfURL: returning nil does not necessarily mean that the file does not exist — it just means that the file could not be read.

Comment: Hey , you give me a very good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of file path are you passing to URLWithString?  If it's a normal path (doesn't start with file://....), then you should be using fileURLWithPath: to convert a string path to a URL.

Answer (score 2):

The two classes are only slightly related.  The first function you use is a convenience method that almost surely uses NSFileManager in the background.  However, otherwise NSData has many many purposes unrelated to files.

Which of the two you use depends on your intent.  If you want to read the contents of the file, you would probably use the first one.  If you want to delete a file if it exists, you would definitely use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

NSData deals with the **content** (or data), maybe of a file, may be not.

NSFileManager deals with a file on file system, e.g., the file's path, copy/move, enumerate folder, check permission, etc. It has more to do with the abstraction of a file rather than the content of the file.